# Having trouble uploading .vcf file into plink

Tags: command-line, bioinformatics, vcf-variant-call-format

I am quite new to coding and using plink and currently having problems trying to upload my vcf file into the plink command prompt.

I typed:

```
plink --vcf [PD630.vcf]
```

But got this error:

> Error: Failed to open [PD630.vcf]. (--vcf expects complete file name; did you forget the .vcf at the end?)

However, I have already typed the complete and accurate file name into the brackets multiple times.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have taken the usage instructions too literally.

It is common when writing out command-line parameters to use square brackets to represent an optional argument, so `--vcf [filename]` would mean "the `--vcf` switch can optionally be followed by a filename". The square brackets don't need to be typed literally, and typing them will make the program look for a file with those brackets *in its name*.

So instead of `plink --vcf [filename.vcf]` you probably want just `plink --vcf filename.vcf`.

Comment: Oh I see, thank you so much for your help! Really appreciate it!